# Why typescript 'async' methods act like a sync till the first 'await' occurrence

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise

Why code executed in the same 'stack' only before first await?

```
 class SomeSyncClass {

  async method(): Promise<void> { 
     console.log('in start async');

     await this.someotherMethod();

    console.log('in finish async');
  }

  someotherMethod(): void { }


  method2(): void {
    console.log('before');
    this.method();
    console.log('after');
  }
}

new SomeSyncClass().method2();
```

output:

```
before 
in start async
after
in finish async
```

But if I remove await - it will be executed synchronously:

```
 class SomeSyncClass {

  async method(): Promise<void> { 
     console.log('in start async');

     this.someotherMethod();

    console.log('in finish async');
  }

  someotherMethod(): void { }


 method2(): void {
   console.log('before');
   this.method();
   console.log('after');
}
}

new SomeSyncClass().method2();
```

output:

```
before
in start async
in finish async
after
```

Comment: In the first example, you must `await this.method();` to get the correct results. As it is now, it returns when it reaches `await this.someotherMethod();` and the rest of it is executed after `this.someotherMethod();` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing happens in both JavaScript and TypeScript. Putting an `await` before an expression that is not a Promise [turns the expression into a resolved Promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description)

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

#### Vanilla JavaScript using `async/await`:

The following snippet is equivalent to your original `await` example. The await causes the synchronous `func3()` to behave as if it is asynchronous, because it has been converted into a resolved `Promise`.

```js
const func3 = () => {}

const func2 = async() => {
  console.log('in start async');
  // The await wraps the synchronous func3 in a resolved Promise.
  await func3();
  console.log('in finish async');
}

const func1 = () => {
  console.log('before');
  func2();
  console.log('after');
}

func1();
```

#### Equivalent JavaScript using a `Promise`:

This next snippet shows what is happening in more detail. I removed the `await` and manually wrapped `func3()` into a resolved `Promise`. That might clarify what is happening.

```js
const func3 = () => {}

const func2 = () => {
  console.log('in start async');

  // This is the equivalent of await func3(); console.log('...');
  Promise.resolve(func3()).then(() => {
    console.log('in finish async');
  });
}

const func1 = () => {
  console.log('before');
  func2();
  console.log('after');
}

func1();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior of async-await style programming.

In this method:

```
async method(): Promise<void> { 
  console.log('in start async');
  await this.someotherMethod();
  console.log('in finish async');
}
```

The second log statement cannot be executed in the same tick as the first because of the await call in the middle. It essentially gets compiled to something like this:

```
async method(): Promise<void> { 
  console.log('in start async');
  this.someotherMethod().then(result => {
    console.log('in finish async');    
  })
}
```

Which, as you can see invokes the second log statement only after `someotherMethod` is resolved.

The second variant, however, is not transformed at all due to async-await rules. Event though `someotherMethod` returns a promise, that promise is simply ignored and dropped out of scope.

These rules have nothing to do with Typescript and are baked in directly to the JavaScript runtime and the ECMA specification.